# How to Consume SOAP 1.2 Web Service Created in WCF by a Java Client?

Tags: java, .net, soap, wcf-binding

I'm developing a Web Service Project in which I have to implement a web service that should be interoperable on all platforms. So initially I used basicHttpBinding as it uses SOAP 1.1 but I want the features of WS-* like reliable messaging, security, exceptions. So I used wsHttpBinding which is a SOAP 1.2 standard.

Now after deploying on my test server I used Netbeans IDE to generate a webservice client. So in return it called the wsimport tool in java to generate proxy classes. When I invoke any method it simply goes into non-working state like there is no activity for 5 mins. So I'm not able to figure out that whether Java client can consume a SOAP 1.2 web service created in WCF?

I need to know if I need to use any other binding than wsHttpBinding for all the features and have interoperability as well.

I don't get any error when i invoke the web method.I tried debugging it but to no help.i set break-point on the line which was invoking the method,when debugger reaches that line then nothing happens, IDE shows running status but there is no activity.If anyone can suggest a tool to monitor Http request to server.

Comment: I started reading this question but got lost when there were no periods. I think it is about interoperability, but not sure what the problem is. can you rewrite, in a few complete sentences?

Comment: Do you get an error message from the Java client or nothing at all? You should at least get some time-out...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried tracing the communication between the Java client and the WCF service?

I would do two things first, turn on logging in WCF; use a trace tool (there are many tike tcptrace) to act as a proxy between the client and server, then point the client at the trace tool and the trace tool at the server. That way you get to see the traffic and the XML (if any) sent back and fore. That should give you a much better idea as to what is going on.

Comment: I checked using HTTP Monitor for XML that is sent to Server and i think problem lies there.(.net) client and java client sends is two diffrent thing.so what i need is to control messages that is sent to server from java client.

Comment: So need to check with your Java toolkit to see if it lets you modify the message. Another option would be to write your client using raw XML APIs rather than rely on the toolkit. That way you have full control over what is sent

Answer (score 0):

Why not configure another endpoint using SOAP 1.1?

Comment: ya, i can do that.but,what i actually need is the features of WS-* which is only available in SOAP 1.2.